# Using Web Services in the Flex Mate Framework

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, asynchronous, mate

I am currently trying to use the "Invocation tags" of Mate to call my web services and delegate the WS-responses to my fault/result handlers.
I want to *use* the *generated proxies*, provided by the Flex Builder, and not the plain `<WebService>` or `<WebServiceInvoker>` tags.

I actually failed using several techniques:

1. `<WebServiceInvoker>` does not work with the generated proxies.
2. `<AsyncMethodInvoker>` needs some complicated successType that I could not get to work with the WS-calls. And defining the events seems redundant to me. I want it simple and easy to read, the code will be touched by other people than me!
3. `<MethodInvoker>` can't use instances, and it also can't handle the proxies' `AsyncToken`
4. `<DelegateInvoker>` Looked fine at first. It calls the service but doesn't fire valid result events (infinite busy cursor). Even though i can successfully bind to the `XYZ_lastResult` of the WS-proxies, and a WS-call results in getting valid data from the WS-backend, the `<faultHandlers>` and `<resulthandlers>` are not executed. There is some solution for the DelegateInvoker that changes code in the generated proxies, which i definately do not want to do!

**So here is my question:** Is there a simple(!) way of using default *Flexbuilder generated proxies* with the *Mate Invocation tags*?

Comment: What's your rationale for using the Mate invokers with the statically generated proxies? The only thing I could think of is... code hinting & typed calls.

Comment: Sorry, I am no longer doing any AS3/Flash/Flex development.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your request is not that uncommon to Mate. Check out this couple of threads in their forum:

http://mate.asfusion.com/forums/topic.php?id=424

http://mate.asfusion.com/forums/topic.php?id=421

The solution is to modify some bits of the auto-generated code... which in a way ruins the whole point of using code generation.